# Split sentences in python, with proper handling of emojis

Tags: python

I want to have an output like this sentence: ['Hi!', 'My name is xyz.', '']

Currently output is like this sentence: ['Hi!', 'My name is xyz.']

Means if emojis are present at last of a text, they should be added in different sentence and should not appended to the same.

```
import emoji

def split_sentences(text):
    sentences = []
    current_sentence = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        current_sentence += text[i]
        if text[i] in ".!?":
            if i + 1 < len(text) and (text[i + 1] == ' ' or emoji.is_emoji(text[i + 1])):
                j = i + 1
                while j + 1 < len(text) and (text[j + 1] == ' ' or emoji.is_emoji(text[j + 1])):
                    current_sentence += text[j + 1]
                    j += 1
                i = j
            sentences.append(current_sentence.strip())
            current_sentence = ''
        i += 1

    # Check if the last character is an emoji
    if current_sentence.strip() != '':
        if emoji.is_emoji(current_sentence.strip()[-1]):
            sentences.append(current_sentence.strip()[:-1])
            sentences.append(current_sentence.strip()[-1])
        else:
            sentences.append(current_sentence.strip())

    return sentences


text = 'Hi!  My name is xyz. '
sentences = split_sentences(text)
print(f"sentences: {sentences}")
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work?  You say: "Means if emojis are present at last of text, they should added in different sentence." In your expected outcome, there is an emoji last to the "Hi!" sentence. Please clarify: When do you want an emoji on an extra line/sentence? Or do you consider the list of string as your text? So you only want to have emojis on the last item in the list of strings on a new line?

Comment: I would split on whitespace, then reconstruct the original sentences "word" by "word". Words containing (only?) emoji get appended to the end of the previous sentence (determined by punctation) until encountering an emoji-free word, which begins a new sentence. I'm sure there are some additional corner cases to work out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import emoji

def split_sentences(text):
    sentences = []
    current_sentence = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        current_sentence += text[i]
        if text[i] in ".!?":
            sentences.append(current_sentence.strip())
            current_sentence = ''
        elif emoji.is_emoji(text[i]):
            j = i + 1
            while j < len(text) and emoji.is_emoji(text[j]):
                current_sentence += text[j]
                j += 1
            sentences.append(current_sentence.strip())
            current_sentence = ''
            i = j - 1
        i += 1

    if current_sentence.strip() != '':
        sentences.append(current_sentence.strip())

    return sentences


text = 'Hi!  My name is xyz. '
sentences = split_sentences(text)
print(f"sentences: {sentences}")
```

Output:

```
sentences: ['Hi!', '', 'My name is xyz.', '']
```

Comment: But output desired  ->  ['Hi!', 'My name is xyz.', '']

Comment: @afghani: The rules are not clear for splitting the emojis off.

Comment: ASCII value can be used (https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-find-and-count-emoticons-in-a-string-using-python)
count = 0
emoticons = set(range(int('1f600',16), int('1f650', 16)))
for row in emoki_text_list:
    for char in row:
        if ord(char) in emoticons:
            count += 1
print("%d emoticons found" % count)

Answer (score 0):

```
#requires python 3.7+

import re, emoji

def split_sentences(text):
    sentences = [i.strip() for i in re.split('(?<=[.!?])', text)]
    for i, v in enumerate(sentences[1:], 1):
        if not (i == len(sentences)-1 and emoji.purely_emoji(v)):
            while emoji.is_emoji(sentences[i][0]):
                sentences[i-1] += sentences[i][0]
                sentences[i] = sentences[i][1:]
            sentences[i] = sentences[i].strip()
    return sentences

text = 'Hi!  My name is xyz. '
sentences = split_sentences(text)
print(f"sentences: {sentences}")
```

Not sure what *all* your rules are for splitting and grouping sentences with emojis, but the above should work. (I confess I did not install the emoji package, so this is not fully tested, but I did test a version with example emojis)

I found it helpful to do the split on punctuation marks (.!?) separately, and this is just a one-liner with regular expressions (needs Python 3.7+ because of zero-length matches).

The rest of the code you can devote to deciding which sentence the emojis end up in - you may want to tweak this to suit rules you may have that I don't know about.